# Intersection of multiple rows in single DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of Temperature 1000s of rows(Time series data) and 40 columns(40 points in a catchment ). Entries in this DataFrame are zeros and one (1 means active part of catchment and zero means non-active part). I want  to place number of intersected values in a separate column(named inter) in the same DataFrame .

I expect the output in this way [attached image]

- value in the first row of inter should be zero as all entries are zero
  and no part is active on day first
- value in the 2nd row of inter should be 4 as four parts are active
  on day 2.
- value in the 3rd row of inter should be 3 (number of intersected values
  of all above rows including 3rd row)[enter image description here][1].
  Green boxes in image show the value for 3rd row
- value in 4th row of inter should be number of intersected values of 
  all above rows (yellow shaded area in the image).
- similarly blue boxes show the value for 5th row and red boxes show 
  the value for sixth row and so on

Note: for every row I will count the intersection of all above rows

[image: Here is Expected Output]

Comment: Your expected output seems different from what you explained in your question. Elaborate it please

Comment: @Sumra Mushtaq post proper input (head()) of data frame and desired output as text

Comment: @SuryaPalaniswamy, I explained it more in detail

Comment: @Sumra Mushraq 5rd row should be calculated as 3rd one or as 4 one? it should go in alternation?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi 5th row and all next rows  should be calculated in the same way as I calculated 4th row (by considering all previous rows ). it does not need alternation. just have to apply method as I applied on 4th row

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I added new image for 5th and 6th row, hopefully you will understand better now

Comment: @SumraMushtaq the 4 row is calculated in 2 steps? As 3rd row and usage of all above rows?

Comment: @SumraMushtaq if i correctly understand this then in 4th row the internet should by 4 instead of 5?

Comment: No I calculated the 4th row in only one step. Simple rule is that I will count the intersection in any row only if 1 is more than one time in any column of that row( e.g in 4th column of 4th row 1 is three time so its an intersection . in the same way in the 8th column of 4th row 1 is 2 times so its an intersection and so on .

Comment: @SumraMushtaq then why is 4th row 9th column counting, and 6th row 11th and 12th columns is not?

Comment: you are right, I am sorry I wrote 5 instead of 4 . you got point correctly in fourth row value should be 4 instead of 5. I updated output. Many thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deserve a reward for this :)
Here is you answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup test data
data = {'0': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], '1': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], '2': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], '3': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], '4': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
, '5': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], '6': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], '7': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], '8': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], '9': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    '10': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], '11': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], '12': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# collect inter data
inter_data = []
for main_index, main_row in data.iterrows():

    # select data for calculations
    selected_data = data.loc[0:main_index,:]

    # handle firs row with 0 values
    if not 1 in main_row.values:
        inter_data.append(0)
    else:
        # handle second row
        if selected_data.shape[0] == 2:
          inter_data.append(selected_data[1:2].values[0].sum())
        # handle rest of data
        else:
            # drop last row from selected data
            selected_data = selected_data[:-1]
            # sum selected data
            summed_data = 0
            for index, row in selected_data.iterrows():
                summed_data += row.values

            # get position of 1
            positions = np.where(main_row.values == 1)
            # get summed data based on position
            positions_data = summed_data[positions[0]]
            # sum occurance in data
            inter_data.append((positions_data >= 1).sum())

# add inter data to raw data
data['inter'] = pd.DataFrame(inter_data)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  inder
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      0
1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   0   0   0      4
2  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   1   0   0      3
3  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   0   1   1      4
4  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   0   1   1      5
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work. you really deserve award :)

Comment: it does work when I apply on whole DataFrame except row 1 (it gives zero value in row 1 instead of 4 ) .

Comment: @SumraMushtaq then post link to you data, or give more lines